# Undefined error in IE11

Tags: javascript, html

I have a classic ASP application that has only started throwing an error in IE11. I have a select tag defined as follows.

```
<SELECT ID='PROJECTS' NAME='PROJECTS' multiple size='15' width='220'  style='width:220px'>
<OPTION VALUE='220'>----</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE='240'>----</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE='228'>----</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE='201'>----</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE='200'>----</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE='260'>----</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

The code is bombing on a call to a JS function .

```
    <a name='REMOVE' href='#' onClick='ModifyFavorites(PROJECTS,FAVORITES,this);'>&lt; Remove</a>
<BR><BR>
```

Comment: Where exactly is the error happening? Where is that function defined? What does the function look like?

Comment: your select tag is invalid. you should put an '<' before SELECT

Comment: What are the values of PROJECTS and FAVORITES? Are they getting used correctly as arguments for ModifyFavorites? You could try switching to addEventListener() instead of the inline handler.

Comment: Fixed it. I enclosed with a document.getElementById for PROJECTS and FAVORITES and it now works for IE11. Strange that every other browser was not a problem